# how do you show custom date format in in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have json data format I am trying to display using highcharts.

```
[{
    "name":"Mobile",
    "data":[
        [1392202800000,682704],
        [1392289200000,707048]
    ]
},
{
    "name":"Web",    
    "data":[
        [1392202800000,902704],
        [1392289200000,807048]
    ]
}]
```

This is data is not continuous meaning is a certain hour in one day.

I need to be able to display this data as Month, Day, Year and hour.

The default is only Month Day and Year.

This is what I have:

```
tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    positioner: function () {
        return {
            x: 60,
            y: 10
        };
    },

    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.percentage:.0f}%)<br/>',
    valueDecimals: 0    
},
```

How could I modify this so that I can also show the hour in the tool tip?

Comment: You could try using the [highcharts tooltip formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter)

Comment: I got it working with xDateFormat option. thanks.